# runOnUiThread from service

Tags: android

I have a method in my service witch must be called from within a thread but I don't want that code to execute in the thread.

How can I call runOnUiThread if I have no activity and I am calling it from a service?

Thanks.

I am not interested in AsyncTask solution!

Comment: Unclear question and ridiculous statement "not interested in AsyncTask"!

Comment: Better would be fire a BroadCastReceiver for the Activity and Update the UI.

Comment: @LalitPoptani i don't have a Activity!

Comment: The only issue I have with this question is "I am not interested in AsyncTask solution!" - why ever not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe a `Handler` can help you. Handler is an element associated to the thread where is created, you can post a runnable with your code to the Handler and that runnable will be executed in the thread where the Handler was created.

Information link: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 4):

The amount of words you are misusing is baffling. `runOnUiThread` is a helper-method to run code on the MAIN-thread. Normally, you use this method when you try to update your UI from a working thread. Since a `Service` doens't have a UI, runOnMainThread would seem highly inappropriate.

You question should be rephrased to either of the following:

- How do I run my code off-MainThread?

Use an `AsyncTask` or an `IntentService`.

- How do I execute code on the MainThread when I am currently in another thread. (Which normally in an `Activity` `runOnUiThread` can be used.)

Create a `Handler` on your `Service` his MainThread and post `Runnables` on it / send messages to it.

Comment: Can not a service make toasts and post notifications? It seems to me then that they do have a UI, albeit not as extensive a UI as an activity would have.

Comment: Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work. More information on this can be found in [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).